# Jenkins Groovy pipeline script to upload to azure VM or BLOB

Tags: azure, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am wondering about any Jenkins Groovy pipeline script support to upload files to Azure BLOB or VM. Any specific class/method to refer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set FTP url for an Azure website and inside Groovy pipeline, use FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient(); and upload the files using Std. methods inside FTPClient. That's it. I can't share the entire code, but telling the approach here so that someone will get help.